# Does tf.function in tensorflow optimize run time?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I read that using `tf. function` can optimize run time by creating a graph and `lazy evaluation`. Following is a sample code of doing matrix multiplication:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def random_sample(x1,x2):
    return tf.matmul(x1,x2)

@tf.function
def random_sample_optimized(x1,x2):
    return tf.matmul(x1,x2)

x1 = tf.constant(tf.random.normal(shape=(3999,29999)))
x2 = tf.constant(tf.random.normal(shape=(29999,3999)))
```

Calculating run time:

```
import time
start = time.time()
op1 = random_sample(x1,x2)
end = time.time()
print (end-start) ## op ~avg = 7 secs

start = time.time()
op2 = random_sample_optimized(x1,x2)
end = time.time()
print (end-start) ##op ~avg = 9.5 secs
```

Not only the average is high when using `tf.function` the individual `run_time` on each and every run was high when using `tf.function`.

Any suggestions on if I am using `tf.function` correctly or it provides optimization only when building complex neural nets?

Comment: A `tf.function` decorated function compiles a static graph on first call. Subsequent calls should be considerably faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tf.function` will usually run faster for complex calculations. Quoting the following lines from the book - 'Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn, Keras, and TensorFlow' along with the example:

> A TF Function will usually run much faster than the original Python function, especially if it performs complex computations. However, in this trivial example, the computation graph is so small that there is nothing at all to optimize, so tf_cube() actually runs much
> slower than cube().

```
def cube(x):
    return x ** 3

>>> cube(2)
8
>>> cube(tf.constant(2.0))
<tf.Tensor: id=18634148, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=8.0>
```

Now, let’s use `tf.function()` to convert this Python function to a `TensorFlow`
Function:

```
>>> tf_cube = tf.function(cube)
>>> tf_cube
<tensorflow.python.eager.def_function.Function at 0x1546fc080>

>>> tf_cube(2)
<tf.Tensor: id=18634201, shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=8>
>>> tf_cube(tf.constant(2.0))
<tf.Tensor: id=18634211, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=8.0>
```